# SSH Mounted Drive, home directory for websites changed

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

A week or so ago I had a new hard drive added onto my dedicated server for additional storage because I am placing a video site up on the server and will be storing a lot of videos. So I wanted to mount this drive onto a directory within the the public_html directory of the new website. This server hosts multiple sites so I created a new directory within the new sites directory called 'Videos' and then mounted the new drive onto this directory. The videos are being uploaded to the new drive with no problem.

I used SSH to do the above commands and I use WHM/CPANEL to create the new site.

Today I needed to add a new site to the server for a customer so I logged into the CPANEL but when I created the new site, the home directory of this site got created in the videos folder as well. When I went to the site I am getting an error: Template Error: The template file must be given (or the template could not be opened).. When I checked the email I received after creating the site I noticed that the HomeRoot was set to /home/videoho/public_html/videos - which is where I mounted the drive for the additional storage. When I SSH into the server and check my home directory, I am not seeing the new site directory here. However, when I

I am not exactly sure how to resolve this issue...

Any assistance is really really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions (or all) of your current `/etc/fstab` file?

Comment: @Mark - It wont let me put everything here but here is a screen shot:

http://filekraze.com/Images/fstab.png

Comment: I don't see the videos volume. Can you post `df` or `mount` output so I can see where it's mounted?

Comment: @Mark Here is a link to a screen shot of df: http://filekraze.com/Images/df.png

Comment: @Mark here is the mount: http://filekraze.com/Images/mount.png

Comment: Ok can you try removing the domain from cPanel (assuming you haven't done a lot of work with it yet), unmount /dev/sdb1, remount it somewhere else if you still need it, then recreate that domain.

Comment: Well I haven't done anything on the domain yet because I really cant access it. There is no directory for it on the server.. even under the site the drive is mounted on, there are no new public_html directories created. most likely due to permissions. My question is, will un mounting the drive cause other issues? I have thought of this but I dont want to kill my other sites as they are working just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little research and hunting around, I found within WHM there is a way to disable the ability to allow for other locations for the home directory. I was able to disable the feature by browsing to "WHM Home » Server Configuration » Basic cPanel & WHM Setup" and update the following option:

"Additional home directories matching the following value will also be used for new home directory creations. (Leaving this value blank disables the feature.) This option only takes one value."

After leaving this option blank, I created a new site and it worked just fine. Thank you for your assistance.